# How to concat a list of lists to a single list with list.map property

Tags: f#

I need to create a single list from a list of lists using the List.map property in f#. This is what i got so far.

```
let lst1 = [[1;2;3;4];[5;6;7;8]]

let concat (list: 'a list list) =
    let li = []
    let q = List.map(fun (x: 'a list) -> x @ li ) list
    li


printfn "%A" (concat lst1)
```

I expect the output

```
li = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
```

but get an empty list instead.

I don't get why the list is empty. I'm adding to the list li in the List.map function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally use [`List.concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.concat%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) for this purpose.

In FSI (the F# REPL):

```
> let lst1 = [[1;2;3;4];[5;6;7;8]];;
val lst1 : int list list = [[1; 2; 3; 4]; [5; 6; 7; 8]]

> List.concat lst1;;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]
```

If you're seeking the challenge of writing this yourself, you might look into [`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B't,'state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The task is to do this without List.concat. I've been told that List.map could do the job, but i'll look into List.fold

Comment: If `concat` is out-of-bounds, then `fold` may be as well. glennsl's answer mentioned the concat operator `@`, the list cons operator is `::`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists

Comment: I looked into List.fold and that did the trick! Thanks a bunch for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the empty list because you return `li` which you have bound to the empty list. Remember that most values are immutable in F#. `x @ li` does not change the list pointed to by `li` in any way.

Here's what your code does, expression by expression:

```
let li = []
```

binds the empty list to the name `li`

```
x @ li
```

evaluates to `x` appended to `li`, but changes neither of them. And since `li` is the empty list, this is equivalent to just `x`. It effectively does nothing.

```
List.map(fun (x: 'a list) -> x @ li ) list
```

maps each element of `list` according to the function passed to it, which we just determined to do nothing. Hence this just creates a one-to-one copy of `list`.

```
let q = ...
```

assigns the copied list to `q`, which is then just discarded since it's not used anywhere.

```
li
```

returns the empty list.

Might I recommend that you start with a tutorial that teaches you the basic concepts underlying F# first? Trial-and-error is usually not a good approach to learning a programming language, and Stack Overflow isn't well suited as a mentoring service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm enrolled in uni and we got this as an assignment, which is why i've posted under the "need help with homework" section. Could you point me in the right direction of how to get x to append to li? even if i make li mutable nothing happens. Also the mutability shouldn't matter when appending to a list. Or so i've learned

Comment: Don't know what the "need help with homework" section is. Anyway, I'd use `List.fold', but you can also write a plain recursive function that goes through each element of the outer list to append it to the result of appending together all the rest of them.